# Shell Script (awk)

Tags: shell, unix, awk

how to extract some lines from a text file using unix shell script awk.

e.g. 
1) input: file_name_test.txt

```
**<header> asdfdsafdsf**  
11 asd sad
12 sadf asdf
13 asdfsa asdf
14 asd sdaf
**15 asd asdfsdf
16 sadfsadfsaf sdfsdf
17 asdf sdaf
18 asfd saf
19 sadf asdf
10 asf asf**
```

2) expected output:

```
**<header> asdfdsafdsf
15 asd asdfsdf
16 sadfsadfsaf sdfsdf
17 asdf sdaf
18 asfd saf
19 sadf asdf
10 asf asf**
```

3) code for test.sh:

```
FILENAME=$1
threshold=$2
awk '{line_count++;
if (line_count==1 || (line_count>$threshold))
print $0;
}' $FILENAME > overflow_new2
```

4)

```
sh test.sh file_name_test.txt 5
```

5) It only prints the first line which is:

```
<header> asdfdsafdsf
```

in the output file overflow_new2. and return these lines in putty:

```
awk: Field $() is not correct.
The input line number is 2. The file is file_name_test.txt
The source line number is 2.
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Can you state clearly what you want to do by the script first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the shell variables to `awk` using `-v` flag:

```
filename=$1
threshold=$2

awk -v thres="$threshold" '
    { line_count++ }
    line_count==1 || line_count > thres { print }
' $filename > overflow_new2
```

When run like:

```
./script.sh file_name_test.txt 5
```

Results/contents of `overflow_new2`:

```
**<header> asdfdsafdsf**  
**15 asd asdfsdf
16 sadfsadfsaf sdfsdf
17 asdf sdaf
18 asfd saf
19 sadf asdf
10 asf asf**
```

Also, to reproduce the desired results exactly, here's the way I'd do it:

```
filename=$1
threshold=$2

awk -v thres="$threshold" '
    FNR == 1 {
        sub(/**\s*$/,"")
        print
    }
    FNR > thres {
        sub(/^**/,"")
        print
    }
' $filename > overflow_new2
```

Comment: Thanks Steve didn't know we need -v. Btw, is there a need for {print $0} instead of {print}? and why thres="$threshold" threshold is pass as string? What if i need thres to do addition condition eg:

    awk -v thres="$threshold" '
    { line_count++ }
    line_count==1 || line_count > thres+thres { print }
    ' $filename > overflow_new2

Comment: By default, `awk` prints the whole line (`$0`), so you can simply write `print`. The same applies to other commands like the `sub()` function. I'm not sure I understand your second request, but you can pass multiple shell variables to `awk` with the `-v` flag. The command you give should also work as you desire.

Comment: Got the $0, thanks. 

Can i do arithmetic operation with the thres variable? since the condition is "line_count==1 || line_count > thres+thres" instead of "line_count==1 || line_count > thres"

Comment: Thanks Steve, worked like a charm. You made my day. Thank you so much. 
awk -v thres="$threshold" '
    { line_count++ }
    line_count==1 || ((line_count > thres) && (line_count <= thres + thres)) { print }
' $FILENAME > overflow_new

Answer (score 1):

Let me fix your script first:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=$1
THRESHOLD=$2

awk -v t=$THRESHOLD '{
        lc++;
        if (lc == 1 || lc > t) {
                print $0;
        }
}' $FILENAME
```

Comment: You don't even need the `lc` variable: `awk -v t=$THRESHOLD 'NR==1 || NR>t' $FILENAME`

Answer (score 0):

Here is Perl code similar to glenn jackman's solution:

```
perl -slne 'print if $. == 1 or $. >= $n' -- -n=15
```

`$.` is the line number